# What permissions are needed for WSO2 SCIM apis

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

What are the permissions required by a role in the Identity server to be able to access the SCIM apis? Can you point me to any docs?

Comment: Have you tried going through this link https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+SCIM+2.0+Provisioning+Connector

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of permissions.

[image]

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/SCIM+2.0+REST+APIs